# Detect email client where email is send

Tags: c#, email, outlook, add-in, outlook-addin

We are create an Outlook plugin.
User can using multi email client on multi device to sending email. 
Then, all email send will sync to Send folder on Outlook.
For some reason, we must to know what email have send by using another email client than Microsoft Outlook.

Is it possible on MailItem class?

Comment: Can you please explain the following: " For some reason, we must to know what email have send by using another email client than Microsoft Outlook." What do you mean?

Comment: Our plugin allow user do business operation and save an email to database when user send it. Of course, we cannot do it on others email client, because we cannot create plugin on all of them. So, we are think about the [Send] folder on Outlook, it's contain all email send by same account. We will look to all emails in Send folder and detect the email client which user using to send it. Then, we will inform them to save to our database. @Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stamp the email sent with your software with a custom user/named property. You can then look for the messages that do not have that property.

Comment: This is simple and clear approach. But, do the MailItem object contain any fields can store custom remark? @Dmitry Streblechenko

Comment: You can use MailItem.UserProperties.Add. Keep in mind that adding a user property can cause Outlook to send in the RTF format. You can avoid by that setting your custom property using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty - make sure it is a named property and just pick a GUID and name. Take a look at the messages with OutlookSpy (click IMessage button) to see the properties and their DASL names (to be used in SetProperty).